# How can I keep the RadioButton text and an additional Label in alignment?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, radio-button, alignment

I'm working on a C# project using .NET 3.5 and Windows Forms. I need to design a decision step with multiple options that require a bit of explanatory text. For this, I want to have a set of RadioButtons to choose an option, followed by an additional Label each that contains the explanation.

[image: example]

I want to keep the label of the radio buttons and the label containing the explanatory text aligned - I've added red lines to the image to illustrate this. I could probably tweak some margins or other settings on the second label, but that would probably start to look weird as soon as the user chooses a different theme or changes some other settings. What is the canonical (and most robust) way to do this?

Comment: @Johnbot Winforms - sorry, forgot to mention that.

Comment: Is adding them to a panel an option?

Comment: How about not using the text of the radio button, but another label instead? This way you will be able to easily align them in design time.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I am under the impression that design time is not the chief concern here.

Comment: Of course it's not the main issue, but it will help also with run time as well...

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer. I think iI would go for owner-drawing; or for not aligning at in the first place..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why I didn't think of this earlier, but the following approach seems to work:

1. Use a TableLayoutPanel with two columns that are set to adjust their width automatically.
2. Place all RadioButtons in the first column and set them to span both columns.
3. Place all Labels in the second column, setting all margins to 0.
4. Add a disabled, but visible (!) "spacer" RadioButton without text in an additional row at the end of the layout.
5. When displaying the form, convert the first column to a fixed size and hide the "spacer".

The key point seems to be that the "spacer" has to be visible initially - otherwise the column will get a size of 0.

This is my test form in the designer:

[image: design view]

To change the layout, I used the following Load handler:

```
    private void TestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // find the column with the spacer and back up its width
        int column = tableLayoutPanel.GetColumn(radioButtonSpacer);
        int width = tableLayoutPanel.GetColumnWidths()[column];
        // hide the spacer
        radioButtonSpacer.Visible = false;
        // set the column to the fixed width retrieved before
        tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles[column].SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
        tableLayoutPanel.ColumnStyles[column].Width = width;
    }
```

And this is the result at runtime:

[image: runtime view]

Comment: You do see that the bottom label is not lined up nicely with the bold "radio button" label, no?

Comment: @BrianWarshaw Strangely, the second and succeeding lines are lined up correctly. It's just the first line that is indented by one single pixel - but that appears to be the case for any multi-line label. Why - beats me...

Answer (score 5):

Your question boils down to two partial problems:

- How large is the RadioButton (or the CheckBox when thinking ahead)..
- How large is the gap between the glyph and the Text.

The first question is trivial:

```
Size  s = RadioButtonRenderer.GetGlyphSize(graphics, 
          System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.RadioButtonState.CheckedNormal);
```

..using a suitable Graphics object. Note that I use the RadioButtonState CheckedNormal as I don't you want the Lables to align differently when the Buttons are checked or unchecked..

The second one is anything but trivial. The gap may or may not be constant and there is another gap to the left of the glyph! If I really wanted to get it right I guess I would write a routine to **measure** the text offset at startup:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    int gapRB = getXOffset(radioButton1);
    int gapLB = getXOffset(label1);
    label1.Left = radioButton1.Left + gapRB - gapLB;
}
```

Here is the measurement function. Note that is doesn't even use the Glyph measurement. Also note that it isn't enough to measure the text offset of the RadioButton.  You also need to measure the offset of the Label!

```
int getXOffset(Control ctl)
{
    int offset = -1;
    string save = ctl.Text; Color saveC = ctl.ForeColor; Size saveSize = ctl.Size;
    ContentAlignment saveCA = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
    if  (ctl is Label)
    {
        saveCA = ((Label)ctl).TextAlign;
        ((Label)ctl).TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomLeft;
    }

    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ctl.ClientSize.Width, ctl.ClientSize.Height))
    using (Graphics G = ctl.CreateGraphics() )
    {
        ctl.Text = "_";
        ctl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        ctl.DrawToBitmap(bmp, ctl.ClientRectangle);
        int x = 0; 
        while (offset < 0 && x < bmp.Width - 1)
        {
            for (int y = bmp.Height-1; y > bmp.Height / 2; y--)
            {
                Color c = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
                if (c.R > 128 && c.G == 0)     { offset = x; break; }
            }
            x++;
        }
    }
    ctl.Text = save;  ctl.ForeColor = saveC;   ctl.Size = saveSize;
    if (ctl is Label)  { ((Label)ctl).TextAlign =  saveCA;   }

    return offset;
}
```

Now the Texts do align pixel perfect..:

[image]

Note that I use two original controls from my form. Therefore much of the code is simply storing and restoring the properties I need to manipulate for the measurement; you can save a few lines by using two dummies.. Also note that I wrote the routine so that it can measure `RadioButtons` and `Labels` and probably `CheckBoxes` as well..

Is it worth it? You decide..!

PS: You could also owner-draw the `RadioButton` and the `Label` text in one.. this would have the interesting side-effect, that the whole text would be clickable..:

[image]

Here is a quick and dirty implementation of owner drawing a CheckBox: Prepare it by setting `AutoSize = false` and by adding the real text together with the extra text into the Tag, separated by a e.g. "§". Feel free to change this setup, maybe using the Label control..

I clear the Text to prevent it from drawing it and I decide on an offset. To measure it, you could use the `GetGlyphSize` from above.. Note how the DrawString method honors embedded '\n' characters.

The Tag contained this string:

> A Rose is a Rose is a Rose..§A Rose is a rose is a rose is a rose is /
>   A rose is what Moses supposes his toes is / Couldn't be a lily or a
>   taffy daphi dilli / It's gotta be a rose cuz it rhymes with mose!

And I for the screenshot I actually used this line:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(texts[1].Replace("/ ", "\n"), ...
```

Here is the `Paint` event:

```
private void checkBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    checkBox1.Text = "";
    string[] texts =  checkBox1.Tag.ToString().Split('§');

    Font font1 = new Font(checkBox1.Font, FontStyle.Regular);

    e.Graphics.DrawString(texts[0], checkBox1.Font, Brushes.Black, 25, 3);
    if (texts.Length > 0)
    {
        SizeF s = e.Graphics.MeasureString(texts[1], checkBox1.Font, checkBox1.Width - 25);
        checkBox1.Height = (int) s.Height + 30;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(texts[1], font1, Brushes.Black, 
                              new RectangleF(new PointF(25, 25), s));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest out-of-the-box solution (it seems to me) would be to use 3 controls instead of 2: a radio button (with the text set to ""), a label (to go beside the radio button) and another label (to go below them). This would allow you easier configuration in designer, but (far more importantly) simpler run-time evaluation and adjustment, if necessary, to keep them in alignment should styles change.

I do understand that this takes away the benefit of clicking the label to select the radio button, but you could add that behavior in the label's `Click` event if you need it.

Alternatively, you could create a `UserControl` containing the text-free radio button and the label, and handle the behavior within that `UserControl` while exposing the label's location.

Comment: But in that case you can't click on the label to select the radiobutton and you would need to handle the label's click event manually. Also the label's mnemonic wouldn't work

Comment: If the label's mnemonic and click functionality are essential, a `UserControl` could be used to contain the radio button and its corresponding label. That way you could also encapsulate the behavior in the `UserControl` and expose the location of the label so that other controls can use it for alignment.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the radiobutton's text being bold, you could set it's label to a multiline string, and set CheckAlign to TopLeft:

```
radioButton2.CheckAlign = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
radioButton2.Text = @"Radiobutton

Explanation text";
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add an invisible dummy label having the same text as the radiobutton. Then, get the length of that label and calculate the correct position of the explanation label.

```
labelDummy.Text = radioButton1.Text;
labelExplanation.Left = radioButton1.Right - labelDummy.Width;
```

However, this still appears to be some pixels off, even though I the label's margin to 0, maybe some additional tweaking can fix this. Here's a screenshot to show what I mean. The label's background is green to be able to see the extra margin.

[image: Radio button alignment]